# React - defined externals modules in webpack config produce "Module not found: Can't resolve" when library is imported

Tags: reactjs, webpack

In a React library - `my-library` - inside Webpack config, I have defined these:

```
...
module.exports = {
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "dist/index.js",
        libraryTarget: "umd",
    },
    ...
    externals: {
        'react': 'react_and_react_dom.React',
        'react-dom': 'react_and_react_dom.ReactDOM',
    },
}
...
```

However, when I import this library in another React project, I get:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/my-library/dist/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react_and_react_dom.React' in '{path_to_main_app}\node_modules\my-library\dist'
```

On the main app - we load React and ReactDOM on the page - thus when I check in the browser - I have these defined:

```
console.log(window.react_and_react_dom)
> Object { React: {…}, ReactDOM: {…} }
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the `externals` like this:

```
externals: {
    "react": {
        "commonjs": "react",
        "commonjs2": "react",
        "amd": "react",
        "root": "React"
    },
    "react-dom": {
        "commonjs": "react-dom",
        "commonjs2": "react-dom",
        "amd": "react-dom",
        "root": "ReactDOM"
    }
},
```

solved my issue.